# Rackspace Cloudfiles and Django Cumulus

Tags: django, rackspace-cloud, cloudfiles

From the past 2 days i have literally lost my patience trying to make Cloudfiles work for my project(using cumulus). Here are some of the issues:

1.) Sometimes when i upload any photo using admin(creating a model and registering with admin)... the photo looks like its uploaded but when i try to either access it using a view function by Photo.objects.all() or even going to the cloudfiles control panel...the image simply doesnt open up. I get a resource not found. I check and double check if the region(chicago is default for me) settings is screwing with me....but i don't think so.

2.) I have used collectstatic method to successfully collect all static files in a container and i am able to successfully serve them. infact when i click the link(say for example) - http://ed770b871265201bf471-14f03984d90730040890dd30a2d85248.r68.cf2.rackcdn.com/admin/css/base.css

I am able to see the results and i am sure u can see it too.

But when i am trying to use them by STATIC_URL in my templates - The admin pages don't have their css working but my login/home pages are perfectly being rendered with my styles.

Here are my settings file/my view functions and anything that is important -

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = 'http://ed770b871265201bf471-14f03984d90730040890dd30a2d85248.r68.cf2.rackcdn.com/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'static'),
)

CUMULUS = {
    'USERNAME': '***',
    'API_KEY': '****',
    'CONTAINER': 'photos',
    'STATIC_CONTAINER':'static',
    'SERVICENET': False, # whether to use rackspace's internal private network
    'FILTER_LIST': [],
    'TIMEOUT' : 60
}
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'cumulus.storage.CloudFilesStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'cumulus.storage.CloudFilesStaticStorage'
```

The model file part

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')
    alt_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)

admin.site.register(Photo)
```

Comment: I am a new user so i can't post images..but i can upload them for reference later if u guys need it.

Comment: Also i am not sure if this is an issue with respect to cumulus or cloud files in general...but i hope i get some help regarding the issues i faced.

Comment: Are you willing to post a link to your site so I can help you debug?

Comment: http://www.disaster-recipe.com/admin/ here you go

Comment: I'm not going to be able to access your admin site directly, but I did create an account on your site (testaccount). I got immediate errors at the profile page. Any other code you can share? Nothing obvious is popping out to me except for this debug line:

`photo = Photo.objects.get(username=username)`

It appears that the code is requesting the username by string rather than id (note that Photo.username is a foreignkey/integer).

Comment: let me look into that. Will try updating the code !

Answer (score 0):

This is the view function as you requested kyle.

```
def profile_detail(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            username = request.user.get_username()
            # userid = User.objects.get(username=username).values('__id')
            userdetails = User.objects.filter(username=username)
            photo = Photo.objects.get(username=request.user.id)
            return render_to_response('profile_detail.html',{'userdetails':userdetails,'username':username,'photo':photo},
                                        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and the template for profile_detail -

```
{% extends 'profile.html' %}

{% load bootstrap_toolkit %}

{% block content %}

    <img src="{{ photo.image.url }}" alt="{{ photo.alt_text }}" />
    <br>
    <p>{{ user.first_name }}</p>
    <p>{{ user.last_name }}</p>
    <p>{{ user.email }}</p>

{% endblock %}
```

I just now checked that i can view the image(No idea how) on the hosted site(production) but still can't do it in my dev environment.

Kyle can you please check if your testaccount has a picture of penguins in the 'MYProfile' page? :) Thanks for looking into it :)

Comment: Went to the page, I see that it's not pulling up the Penguins.jpg resource. :( However, I did notice that the photos directory pulls up (deleted Penguins.jpg off the URL). Have you put a ticket in with Rackspace to have them look at that specific file? They usually respond very quickly and do their best to help.

Answer (score 0):

The images *are there*, but possibly not where you expected them.

Link on your current site:

http://d12df125d01b8a258a3a-8112fdc02f7d385b44f56eb9e899d81c.r88.cf2.rackcdn.com/photos/Penguins.jpg

Where the image/file actually is:

http://d12df125d01b8a258a3a-8112fdc02f7d385b44f56eb9e899d81c.r88.cf2.rackcdn.com/photos%5CPenguins.jpg

The `%5C` is a `\` rather than a `/`. This makes a difference as these are keys (key being the "path" and value being the file). You may want to check on how these were uploaded, and possibly normalize them to regular slashes (were these uploaded while you were on a Windows machine?).

Comment: Yes they were uploaded from a windows machine. how do u normalize them? I am actually using django's admin to upload them for now.

Comment: Personally, I would just change the path/name of the Penguins file to have the proper slash or upload another with the right path. All others should come out the same using Cumulus. It would probably be worth it to put unit tests in place for this.